# auth0 roles not passed along on signup

Tags: php, authentication, sdk, auth0

I am using Auth0 PHP SDK, to build a regular web app.

When users signup they are assigned a role (via a Rule). I wish to know that role (through access token) to determine what content to show them.

The issue here seems to be that the access token is supplied prior to the Rule applying a role.

Thus, I believe I would need to force a token refresh after login to get the roles.

My issue is that I am currently unsure on how to do this. This is my login code:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ . '/dotenv-loader.php';

session_start();
$return_to = $_SESSION['return_uri'];

$auth0 = new Auth0\SDK\Auth0([
    'domain' => getenv('AUTH0_DOMAIN'),
    'client_id' => getenv('AUTH0_CLIENT_ID'),
    'redirect_uri' => $return_to,
    'audience' => getenv('AUTH0_AUDIENCE'),
    'scope' => 'openid profile email',
]);

$auth0->login();
```

I then search for roles as below:

```
$userInfo = $auth0->getUser();
$roles = $userInfo['https://www.example.com/roles'];
```

Can someone help me implement a PHP solution?

FYI, if a user signs out then back in then it works fine, hence this is only an issue on signup. Ideally, the solution would check for the role before requesting a new access token so that it doesn't do so on every log in, just on sign up.

Thanks for any help